# Rejected after 3rd interview - now they want to interview again

Tags: interviewing, job-search, rejection, reinterviewing

A few months ago I interviewed for a position. After a phone interview and two in-person interviews, I received a rejection notice from the recruiter with no other explanation.

Last Friday, I was contacted by the same recruiter. He told me that the company asked to interview me again. I'm not sure why the other person did not work out or why they did not want me in the first place.  It is a company that is known for hiring internally - so it could have been as simple as that. Or, it could have been that I was not on my A-game at the third interview. I was exhausted from a string of interviews at 2 different companies and I felt like there were a few questiosn I could have answered a bit better.

I have this new, re-interview tomorrow. How should I approach it? They asked to re-interview me, so we are all aware that they already rejected me once.

Any suggestions? I want to WOW them this time!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do other interviews and get some rest? Just because  you didn't get an offer doesn't mean you had a poor interview. Someone else could have had more experience or other factors that are out of your control.

Comment: Not being selected is a far cry short of being rejected.  Being second-pick in a crowded field has advantages, as you appear to be seeing, now.

Comment: Go over the questions you could have done better. Then have a good night's sleep, show up early and be relaxed thoughout.

Comment: To add to Wesley's answer, in all likelihood you are the only candidate for this new interview - if #1 on the original list didn't work out, and #2 is still interested, why bother dragging #3, #4 etc. back? Do prepare as suggested, but relax - you've done a lot of the hard work already to get this far. And make sure you're consistent with the first interview - don't rewrite history to impress them.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me, the message the recruiter got was that the employer liked #1, but in fact #1 was a turkey (I was #2).  So it was due to the recruiter.  That said, probably #1 in your case didn't work out for whatever reason.  So go for it, be calm, learn from your mistakes.  I have made plenty of dumb mistakes in interviews.

Answer (score 6):

**Prepare, but relax**

- Review your notes from your prior interviews
- Double-check any research you did on the company, in case anything has changed
- Make sure you have the names of the folks who interviewed you before
  (being able to match faces to names would be best)
- Make some notes on what you've done since the last interview
- Get plenty of rest

If you show up prepared and interested, you will likely appear a little bit better than you did the first time. Obviously, you almost made the cut. It's possible this is a new position or it may be the same position because their first choice didn't work out. So, you're already in the finals. Just relax and be yourself.